# Callback function not being called in Scrapy after Redirection

Tags: python, scrapy

I have a minimal crawler that I have created as follows-

```
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from sandbox.items import SandboxItem

class SandboxCrawlSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'sandbox_crawl'
    allowed_domains = ['amazonaws.com']
    start_urls = ['http://www.amazonaws.com/']
    rules = (
        Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(), callback=('parse_item'), follow=True),
    )

    def parse_item(self, response):
        sel = Selector(response)
        i = SandboxItem()
        print response.url

        return i
```

The issue here is that the  domain I have allowed ,`amazonaws.com`, redirects to `aws.amazon.com`.

After redirection the crawler crawls through the page but never calls the callback function. The output is something like

```
2014-03-05 15:50:56+0530 [sandbox_crawl] DEBUG: Redirecting (301) to <GET http://aws.amazon.com> from <GET http://www.amazonaws.com/>
2014-03-05 15:50:58+0530 [sandbox_crawl] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://aws.amazon.com> (referer: None)
2014-03-05 15:50:58+0530 [sandbox_crawl] DEBUG: Filtered offsite request to 'aws.amazon.com': <GET http://aws.amazon.com/>
2014-03-05 15:50:58+0530 [sandbox_crawl] DEBUG: Filtered offsite request to 'portal.aws.amazon.com': <GET https://portal.aws.amazon.com/gp/aws/developer/registration/index.html>
2014-03-05 15:50:58+0530 [sandbox_crawl] DEBUG: Filtered offsite request to 'console.aws.amazon.com': <GET https://console.aws.amazon.com/>
2014-03-05 15:50:58+0530 [sandbox_crawl] DEBUG: Filtered offsite request to 'www.youtube.com': <GET http://www.youtube.com/embed/mZ5H8sn_2ZI?autoplay=1&hd=1&rel=0>
2014-03-05 15:50:58+0530 [sandbox_crawl] DEBUG: Filtered offsite request to 'youtube.com': <GET http://youtube.com/embed/jOhbTAU4OPI?autoplay=1&hd=1&rel=0>
2014-03-05 15:50:58+0530 [sandbox_crawl] DEBUG: Filtered offsite request to 'www.powerof60.com': <GET http://www.powerof60.com/?00N500000026nJd=BA_AWSHP_IntelAWS_Generic&sc_icampaign=ha_en_intel_power_of_60_ed&sc_icampaigntype=partners&sc_ichannel=ha&sc_icountry=us&sc_ipage=homepage&sc_iplace=editorial_r3_right_banner&utm_campaign=BA_AWSHP_IntelAWS&utm_content=GenericAWS&utm_medium=banner&utm_source=AWSHP>
2014-03-05 15:50:58+0530 [sandbox_crawl] DEBUG: Filtered offsite request to 'aws.typepad.com': <GET http://aws.typepad.com/>
2014-03-05 15:50:58+0530 [sandbox_crawl] DEBUG: Filtered offsite request to 'phx.corporate-ir.net': <GET http://phx.corporate-ir.net/phoenix.zhtml?c=176060&p=irol-InfoReq>
2014-03-05 15:50:58+0530 [sandbox_crawl] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
```

As seen the parse_item is never called .'print response.url' has no effect, neither does any other statement in the function. Is there any error in the spider?

Answer (score 0):

Just add `"aws.amazon.com"` to `allowed_domains`

```
allowed_domains = ['amazonaws.com', 'aws.amazon.com']
```

Comment: Yes. That is an option. But given a list of URLs containing domains such as 'gmail.com' and 'amazonaws.com', I want the crawler to automatically parse the redirected urls too, without manual intervention. This is a static case. In my program I'd read the list of allowed domains from a file.

Comment: Try disabling [OffsiteMiddleware](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spider-middleware.html#scrapy.contrib.spidermiddleware.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware)

Answer (score 0):

add dont_filter=True to request, but this does not eventually solve the problem.

like this:

```
Request('http://example.org/', callback = self.func, dont_filter=True)
```